# Joining multiple tables makes the query run too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several tables, containing (a.o.) the following fields:

```
tweets:
--------------------------
tweet_id ticker created_at
--------------------------
1        1      1298063318
2        1      1298053197

stocks:
---------------------------------
ticker date        close volume
---------------------------------
1      1313013600  12.25 40370600
1      1312927200  11.60 37281300

wiki:
-----------------------
ticker date       views
-----------------------
1      1296514800   550
1      1296601200   504
```

I want to compile an overview of # of tweets, close, volume and views per day (for rows identified by ticker = 1). The tweets table is leading, meaning that if there is a date on which there are no tweets, the close, volume and views for that day don't matter. In oter words, I want the output of a query to be like:

```
-------------------------------------
date        tweets close volume views
-------------------------------------
2011-02-13  4533   12.25 40370600 550
2011-02-14  6534   11.60 53543564 340
2011-02-16  5333   13.10 56464333 664
```

In this example output, there were no tweets on 2011-02-15, so there is no need for the rest of the data of that day. My query thus far goes:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tweets.created_at), '%Y-%m-%d') AS date, 
  COUNT(tweets.tweet_id) AS tweets,
  stocks.close,
  stocks.volume,
  wiki.views
FROM tweets
LEFT JOIN stocks ON tweets.ticker = stocks.ticker
LEFT JOIN wiki ON tweets.ticker = wiki.ticker
WHERE tweets.ticker = 1
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Could someone verify if this query is correct? It doesn't run into any errors but it freezes my PC. Perhaps I should set an index here or there, possibly on the "ticker" columns?

[edit]

As requested, the table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
  `ticker` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `high` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `low` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `close` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `volume` int(8) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
  `tweet_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticker` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `id_str` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `from_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tweet_id`),
  KEY `id_str` (`id_str`),
  KEY `from_user` (`from_user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `wiki` (
  `ticker` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you post the table definitions `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`?

Comment: See the editted TS. I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do believe you should check the joins between the tables. Your query does not indicate which stocks-rows (or wiki-row) is to be matched to the date for tweets. Based on example data the match is done for all stocks and wiki-rows which have the same ticker_id.

Does stocks and wiki-tables have only one row for certain day for one ticker? Assuming this is the case, more logical query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.created_at), '%Y-%m-%d') AS date, 
  COUNT(t.tweet_id) AS tweets,
  s.close,
  s.volume,
  w.views
FROM tweets t
  LEFT JOIN stocks s ON t.ticker = s.ticker 
       and FROM_UNIXTIME(t.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d')=FROM_UNIXTIME(s.date,'%Y-%m-%d')
  LEFT JOIN wiki w ON t.ticker = w.ticker
       and FROM_UNIXTIME(t.created_at,'%Y-%m-%d')=FROM_UNIXTIME(w.date,'%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE tweets.ticker = 1
GROUP BY date, s.close, s.volume, w.views
ORDER BY date ASC
```

If there are more than one row in stocks/wiki for certain day for one ticker, the you need to apply aggregate function to those columns as well and change the COUNT(t.tweet_id) to COUNT(distinct t.created_at).

Answer (score 2):

You are right about indices, without an index on ticker you would have to do a where-search in all tables and if they are big that's going to take alot of time.

I suggest that you turn on [logging of all queries that run without index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-queries-not-using-indexes) at least every now and then to find queries that if not already are slow will be slow when the data increases.

Check queries with `[EXPLAIN SELECT ...][2]` if you find them slow, learn how to interpret the results (not easy but important) to understand where to put new indices.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one of problems is date calculation

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tweets.created_at), '%Y-%m-%d') date
```

Try to add this field to the tweets table to avoid CPU consumption

edit:
you can use something like this

```
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
  `ticker` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `high` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `low` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `close` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `volume` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `day_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
  `tweet_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticker` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `id_str` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `from_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `day_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tweet_id`),
  KEY `id_str` (`id_str`),
  KEY `from_user` (`from_user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `wiki` (
  `ticker` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `day_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


SELECT 
tweets.day_date AS date, 
COUNT(tweets.tweet_id) AS tweets,
stocks.close as close,
stocks.volume as volume,
wiki.views as views
FROM tweets
LEFT JOIN stocks ON tweets.ticker = stocks.ticker 
                and tweets.day_date = stocks.day_date
LEFT JOIN wiki ON tweets.ticker = wiki.ticker
              and tweets.day_date = wiki.day_date
WHERE tweets.ticker = 1
GROUP BY date, close, volume, views
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Would that be possible to do with a query (after I have created an additional column, say "full_date" in the tweets table?